# why notification message is not showing in off canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

this my balance.html code

```
{% extends "money/index.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

<div class="blatitle">
    Balance
</div>

<div class="bladiv">
<div class="amtext">
Available Amount : ₹ {{ user.bankaccount.balance}}
</div>
</div>


<button id="notification-button" onclick="toggleOffCanvas()">
    Notification
    <span id="notification-badge" class="badge badge-danger">{{ unread_notifications|length }}</span>
  </button>

  <div id="offCanvas">
    <!-- Off-canvas content -->
    <div id="offCanvasContent">
      <ul id="notification-list">
        {% for notification in unread_notifications %}
          <li>{{ notification.message }} <button class="mark-as-read" data-notification-id="{{ notification.id }}">Mark as Read</button></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% if unread_notifications %}
        <button id="mark-all-as-read">Mark All as Read</button>
      {% else %}
        <p>No notifications.</p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        // AJAX to mark a notification as read
        $(".mark-as-read").click(function () {
            var notificationId = $(this).data("notification-id");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/mark_notification_as_read/",
                data: { notification_id: notificationId },
                success: function () {
                    // Reload the page or update the UI as needed
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error("Error marking notification as read:", error);
                },
            });
        });

        // AJAX to mark all notifications as read
        $("#mark-all-as-read").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/mark_all_notifications_as_read/",
                success: function () {
                    // Reload the page or update the UI as needed
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error("Error marking all notifications as read:", error);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>










{% endblock %}
```

this is my views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .models import User,Transaction,BankAccount, UserProfile,Notification
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse
from decimal import Decimal
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import formedu, formhome
from django.db.models import Max






# Create your views here.
@login_required
def index(request):
   

     
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
     # Get unread notifications for the user
    unread_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user, read=False)

    return render(request, "money/index.html", {
        "user": request.user,
        "user_profile": user_profile,
        "unread_notifications": unread_notifications,
    })    
    



@login_required
def mark_notification_as_read(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        notification_id = request.POST.get("notification_id")
        try:
            notification = Notification.objects.get(id=notification_id)
            notification.read = True
            notification.save()
            return JsonResponse({"success": True})
        except Notification.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({"success": False, "message": "Notification not found."})

    return JsonResponse({"success": False, "message": "Invalid request method."})

@login_required
def mark_all_notifications_as_read(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user, read=False).update(read=True)
        return JsonResponse({"success": True})

    return JsonResponse({"success": False, "message": "Invalid request method."})

   

 





def balance(request):
    try:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        bank_account = BankAccount.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        user_profile = None
        bank_account = None

    # Check balance and add a notification if it's under 20
    if bank_account and bank_account.balance < 20:
        create_notification(request.user, "Low Balance: Your account balance is below 20.")

   

    return render(request, "money/balance.html", {"user": request.user, "user_profile": user_profile})



def create_notification(user, message):
    Notification.objects.create(
        user=user,
        message=message,
    )
    



def login_in(request):
    if request.method =="POST":

     name = request.POST['name']
     password = request.POST['password']

     user = authenticate(request,username=name, password=password)

     if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
     else:
        return render(request,"money/login.html",{
           "message":"Invalid Name or Password"
        })
     
    else:
       return render(request, "money/login.html")
    


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.FILES)  # Add this line to print request.FILES
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        date = request.POST['date']
        mobile = request.POST['mobile']
        address = request.POST['address']
        tcode = request.POST['tcode']
        
        # Use request.FILES for file uploads (like images)
        image = request.FILES['image']
        if 'image' in request.FILES:
            image = request.FILES['image']
        else:
            return render(request, "money/register.html", {
                "message": "Please select an image."
            })
       
        password = request.POST['password']
        cpassword = request.POST['cpassword']
        
        # Check if passwords match
        if password != cpassword:
            return render(request, "money/register.html", {
                "message": "Password must match."
            })
        

         
      
        try:
            # Create a user instance
            user = User.objects.create_user(name, email, password)
            user.save()

            # Authenticate the user
            auth_user = authenticate(request, username=name, password=password)

            # Log in the user
            login(request, auth_user)

            # Create a BankAccount instance for the user
            bank_account = BankAccount(user=request.user, balance=100.00)
            bank_account.save()

            # Create a user profile instance
            profile = UserProfile(
                user=request.user,  # Associate with the authenticated user
                date_of_birth=date,
                mobile_number=mobile,
                address=address,
                mcode=tcode,
                image=image,
            )
            profile.save()

            # Redirect to the index page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        except IntegrityError:
            # Handle duplicate user creation
            return render(request, "money/register.html", {
                "message": "User with this email already exists."
            })
        except ValidationError:
            return render(request, "money/register.html", {
                "message": "Invalid data submitted."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "money/register.html")
```

this is my index.html code

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Bank{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'money/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="bg" style="background-image: url('{% static "money/bg.jpg"%}')"; style="background-image: url('{% static "money/bg.jpg"%}')";>
    <div class="col-md-6 indexdiv">
        <h1 class="indextitle">Gautam Bank</h1>
        <div class="indexsign">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                Signed in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.
            {% else %}
                Not signed in.
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'balance' %}">Balance</a>
            </li>
            
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'send' %}">Send Money</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link history-link" href="{% url 'history' %}">Transaction History</a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'loan' %}">Apply for Loan</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Logout</a>
                </li>
            
        </ul>
        
        <hr>
       
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 indeximg">
             {% if user_profile and user_profile.image %}
               <img height="138" width="152" src="{{ user_profile.image.url }}" alt="User Profile Image">
             {% else %}
               <img height="138" width="152" src="{% static 'money/pic.jpg' %}" alt="Default Image">
             {% endif %}
       </div>
      

      




<script>
   

     function toggleOffCanvas() {
        const offCanvas = document.getElementById('offCanvas');
        const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        const isVisible = offCanvas.style.right === '0px';

        // Toggle the off-canvas visibility
        offCanvas.style.right = isVisible ? '-250px' : '0';
        // Toggle the overlay visibility
        overlay.style.display = isVisible ? 'none' : 'block';
    }

    // Add event listener to close off-canvas when clicking outside of it
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        const offCanvas = document.getElementById('offCanvas');
        const notificationButton = document.getElementById('notification-button');
        const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

        // Check if the click is outside the off-canvas and notification button
        if (event.target !== offCanvas && event.target !== notificationButton) {
            // Close the off-canvas
            offCanvas.style.right = '-250px';
            // Hide the overlay
            overlay.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

</script>
        
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my urls.py code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.login_in,name="login"),
    path("register",views.register,name="register"),
    path("index", views.index,name="index"),
    path("history",views.history, name="history"),
    path("loan",views.loan,name="loan"),
    path("balance",views.balance,name="balance"),
    path("send", views.send, name="send"),
    path('send_money_api/', views.send_money_api, name='send_money_api'),
    path('history/', views.history, name='transaction_history'),
    path('loanform', views.loanform, name="loanform"),
    path('formEdu',views.formEdu  , name="formEdu"),
    path('formHome',views.formHome,name="formHome"),
    path("mark_notification_as_read/",views.mark_notification_as_read, name="mark_notification_as_read"),
    path("mark_all_notifications_as_read/", views.mark_all_notifications_as_read, name="mark_all_notifications_as_read"),
    
    

   

]



# Serve uploaded media files during development
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is my models.py code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin





class BankAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=100.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Bank Account"

class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    serial_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # Add this line


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}: {self.message}"
```

**now the problem is that when user balance is below 20, there is no notification in the off canvas, i checked my all javascript and other i can't find the problem please help , and if you have any other approach so please tell that also  **

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.